when and where are newly granted utility patents published?
I am currently trying find a patent that has just been granted. Where do I go to search for it? I am not sure if it is actually granted yet or announced that it would be granted.

The Official Gazette for Patents is published every Tuesday (on line) by the USPTO. It lists all patents issued that day.
A better way to search these is with the generic USPTO search facility and qualify on issue date. You can qualify on applicant, inventor etc. It should be visible here on the day of issue.
Patent search sites like the Lens and Google patents might lag that by a week or more before they show it.

In the Gazette website, can you search by inventor name?

I improved the answer to be more helpful.
